# Add class to WooCommerce pages via custom checkbox in WooCommerce product settings

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields

I have a problem with the code below. With that code, we can select specific product and give them a different style in the shop archive. This is working.

However, I guess there is a error in the code.

Once I activated the checkbox for a product, it always appears in the new style even when I uncheck the checkbox. I assume that I made a error with the `get_post_meta` object.

Can someone help me with that?

Code to display the check box in the general product settings and add the class, based on the value in the check box

```php
// Add checkbox
function action_woocommerce_product_general_options_product_style_listing_data() {
    // Checkbox
    woocommerce_wp_checkbox( array( 
        'id'             => '_special_product_listing_style', // Required, it's the meta_key for storing the value (is checked or not)
        'label'          => __( 'Special style', 'woocommerce' ), // Text in the editor label
        'desc_tip'       => false, // true or false, show description directly or as tooltip
        'description'    => __( 'Promote a product by changing the style of the product card', 'woocommerce' ) // Provide something useful here
    ) );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'action_woocommerce_product_general_options_product_style_listing_data', 10, 0 );
        
// Save Field
function action_woocommerce_product_general_options_product_style_listing_save( $product ) {
    // Isset, yes or no
    $checkbox = isset( $_POST['_special_product_listing_style'] ) ? 'yes' : 'no';

    // Update meta
    $product->update_meta_data( '_special_product_listing_style', $checkbox );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'action_woocommerce_product_general_options_product_style_listing_save', 10, 1 );

// Is_special style
function filter_woocommerce_post_class( $classes, $product ) {    
    if ( get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_special_product_listing_style', true ) ) {
        $classes[] = 'custom-product-listing-class';
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_post_class', 'filter_woocommerce_post_class', 10, 2 );
```

---

CSS to style the specific products:

```css
/* Custom special product listing style */
li.sales-flash-overlay.woocommerce-text-align-left.woocommerce-image-align-center.do-quantity-buttons.product.type-product.post-10800.status-publish.first.instock.product_cat-crafty-beer-club.has-post-thumbnail.featured.sold-individually.taxable.shipping-taxable.product-type-variable.custom-product-listing-class {
    border: 2px solid;
    border-style: dashed;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```php
// Is_special style
function filter_woocommerce_post_class( $classes, $product ) {    
    if ( get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_special_product_listing_style', true ) ) {
        $classes[] = 'custom-product-listing-class';
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_post_class', 'filter_woocommerce_post_class', 10, 2 );
```

With

```php
// Is_special style
function filter_woocommerce_post_class( $classes, $product ) {
    // Get meta
    $spls = $product->get_meta( '_special_product_listing_style' );
    
    // Compare
    if ( $spls == 'yes' ) {
        $classes[] = 'custom-product-listing-class';
    }
    
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_post_class', 'filter_woocommerce_post_class', 10, 2 );
```

---

That should suffice for your code to function fully

Comment: Yep! That was the error! Why I have to use here a different way with a variable?

Comment: As your code is written, the if condition will always be met, if a value for the checkbox exists. In my code this is only executed if a value exists AND it is equal to 'yes'